# internal testing or beta testing are updates are not showing

Tags: android, react-native, google-play, google-play-console

I'm Facing issues some issues in the release testing app in the Google play console.

I'm using React Native, I Recently updated the React native Version. After that the app publish is not working. However, the app is approved. I submitted an app updated in Internal Testing and also Close testing.

But Before the version updates the app getting live in 10min, I waited for 2day but still, the app is not live in Internal Testing and Close testing.

What were these issues?

Comment: are you using play store app to check the updates? on some mobile phone play store I notice it's not refreshing directly, try check it from web to check the newest version, e.g: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ss.android.ugc.trill, or you can clear the cache for play store app to get the new data.

Comment: Please check if an app is still in review mode